# How to start creating a language extension for VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, xhtml, vscode-extensions, tooling, languageservice

Pursuant to the discussion in [Add XHTML support](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111447), I'd like to start creating an extension for Visual Studio Code which would implement support for XHTML. Which is HTML with XML syntax, so the the desired functionality is already (mostly?) implemented elsewhere – for XML and HTML languages, the latter having two extensions bundled with VS Code: `html` and `html-language features`. But it's disparate.

As the first step, should I clone the VS Code repo and delete everything except the two directories named `html` and `html-language features`? Or [Language services for HTML](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-html-languageservice)? Or the latter and `html` from the former? Or start with `html`, make it work for XHTML and only then deal with language features?

Should the second step be just adding the extension(s) I'm developing on my computer to my installation of VS Code? The GUI seems to allow adding only extensions from the Visual Studio Marketplace. Is it the right solution to place the extensions under development into VS Code's directory for extensions (either directly or with symbolic links)? I'm on Manjaro Linux.

If you can offer any other helpful advice, I welcome it too.

Comment: So to be honest, I ask questions that are too broad, more often than I ask questions that are good, well at first anyways — the ability to edit my questions makes it possible for me to work on my question while its publicly posted, and not always, but a more often than not, I can usually narrow my question down to a few very specific sentences that address a single idea (or concept) that If I can get an answer to I can usually progress on what ever issue I am having.

Comment: I say this, because being on the otherside of the table, and trying to answer your question, I can tell you, its a bit hard. You ask a few different question, which is okay, I know your trying to understand, and I want to give a good answer, but I need some help to better understand what it is you need to know, what core concept or idea can I help you come to understand. The best way that you could help me, and the rest of the community would likely be to narrow your question down a bit, to a single precise question.

Comment: @JΛY-ÐΞV, thanks for your willingness to guide me towards a desirable resolution. In my question there are two steps I'm considering, the first of which has variants (though I'm open of course to suggestions of superior alternatives I didn't mention). I could narrow the question to just the first step. Or even ask multiple questions of the form: is A a good first step, is B a good first step, is C a good first step? But the point is I've never done it, for me it holds many unknown unknowns, and the optimal setup isn't trivial. So I think it may instead be helpful if I rephrase the problem.

Comment: If you, the person answering this question, presumably more knowledgeable than me in this area, were to pursue this goal, what steps would you take before actually writing any code (be it from scratch or modifying existing)? (If the steps and possibilities I listed as under consideration are completely wrong, I'd also like to be corrected.)